# How do I add an image for each menu column?

Tags: views, routes

I have 4 columns in the footer, and am displaying a different menu in each block(column). I would like to add an image above the menu items for 3 out of 4 menus. What is the best way to do this? Is it possible to add a field to the menu content type as such? If this was possible I could then create a view for each block/column, by pulling in the menu items and images...

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You can create a menu blocks using menu block module and  alter the render of block to add the image.

Comment: Thank you for that @mohit_rocks
What exactly do you mean by "alter the render of block "?

Comment: to append the image you can use hook_block_view_alter() function. This hook allows you to modify any data returned by hook_block_view(). https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7

Comment: Are your blocks a menublock creations, or what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do that with CSS

```css
#column-1{
  padding-top:20px; /* Space for image */
  background: transparent url('../images/bg-col-1.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the "easiest" way to make the change from among the listed solutions. The only fly-in-the-ointment is that there's no UI for changing the image after the site is handed off, or is there?

Comment: Thank you @David-thomas
I was hoping for the image to be editable via the cms, but this is too easy not to implement as is. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, if you want to get slightly more fancy, you may want to consider using a CSS sprite and background-position to combine the images into one.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you need to add individual image for each menu item in a particular menu block you can use this module

You can try [Menu Attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. You can add specific class and do the css.

This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.